# Google Script to show/hide rows very slow (and crashing)

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to filter a sheet based on a cell (A1) by hiding and showing the appropriate rows. It is working, but since the sheet gets bigger every year, it is already running very slowly as it hides/unhides row by row. I want to somehow batch these and perform the hide/unhide functions just once. Unfortunately, I'm not having luck doing that. Here is the code that is working for the two sheets, but far too slowly (so slow that sometimes it crashes):

```
function chooseYearAdj() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ADJUSTMENTS");
var yrCell = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
//  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); extra unnecessary var?
  var allRange = sheet.getRange("A3:A")
  var i=1
  if (yrCell == "ALL" || yrCell == "all"){
//      var rowAll = sheet.getRange("A:A"); extra unnecessary var?
      sheet.unhideRow(allRange);
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.hideRow(allRange); // hides all rows below header
  while ( sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue() != "") { // i <= last interesting row
    {
    var year = sheet.getRange("R"+i).getValue();  // Checks the R column
       if (year == yrCell) {         // year == chosen year
         var rowHide = sheet.getRange("A"+i);
         sheet.unhideRow(rowHide);
       }
      i=i+1
    }
  }
}
}

function chooseYearTS() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TEAM SALES");
var yrCell = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
//  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); extra unnecessary var?
  var rowRange = sheet.getRange("A:A")
  var i=3
  if (yrCell == "ALL" || yrCell == "all"){
    sheet.unhideRow(rowRange); //shows all rows
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.unhideRow(rowRange); // shows all rows below header
  while ( sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue() != "") { // i <= last interesting row
    {
    var year = sheet.getRange("CC"+i).getValue();  // Checks the R column
       if (year != yrCell && year != "") {         // year is neither blank nor the chosen year.
         var rowHide = sheet.getRange("A"+i);
         sheet.hideRow(rowHide);
       }
      i=i+1
    }
  }
}
}
```

The second of these is much slower even than the first. I tried creating the range within the while loop, and then hiding/showing the entire range, but that didn't change anything. This is that code, which I admit, may have syntax errors as this was a new attempt for me:

```
function chooseYearAlt() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ADJUSTMENTS");
var yrCell = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
//  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); extra unnecessary var?
  var allRange = sheet.getRange("A3:A")
  var i=1
  var toHide = sheet.getRange()
  if (yrCell == "ALL" || yrCell == "all"){
//      var rowAll = sheet.getRange("A:A"); extra unnecessary var?
      sheet.unhideRow(allRange);
    }
    else
    {
      sheet.hideRow(allRange); // hides all rows below header
  while ( sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue() != "") { // i <= last interesting row
    {
    var year = sheet.getRange("R"+i).getValue();  // Checks the R column
       if (year == yrCell) {         // year == chosen year
         toHide = toHide + sheet.getRange("A"+i);


//         var rowHide = sheet.getRange("A"+i);
//         sheet.unhideRow(rowHide);
       }
      i=i+1
    }
    sheet.unhideRow(toHide);
  }
}
}
```

The problem I have here is that there is no guarantee that the year column will remain in order, so I can't just find the first row with the right year and then hide the right number of rows after it, as some day, they may end up more mixed.

Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Comment: Can you not sort them by year at the start of the script then hide the rows en masse? Using `hideRows()` will perform much better than looping and hiding each one.

Comment: I don't think so, because most of the columns are imported in from another sheet. Sorting messes up the importrange function, at least as far as I've seen.  I wish I could share the sheets so everyone could see this better, but it is private home buyer information and linked among 3 sheets, all with this private data

Comment: I've also recently had the idea to add a helper column which returns A+row number for any rows which should be shown. I then used concatenate to create a helper cell with the full list of rows to show, as: A1,A2,A5,A10,A50 - etc. However, no matter how I format that ("A1,A2" ; ['A1','A2'] ; etc.) when I use getRangeList to decide what to show in the script, it returns the error "Cannot find function getRangeList in object". So, perhaps solving that issue would fix the problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a faster alternative for your chooseYearAlt function:

```
function chooseYearAlt() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ADJUSTMENTS");
  var yrCell = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var allRange = sheet.getRange("A3:A");

  sheet.unhideRow(allRange);

  if (yrCell != "ALL" && yrCell != "all"){
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var year
    for (var i = 3;i<lastRow;i++) {
      year = sheet.getRange(i, 18).getValue(); // The 18 means column R
      if (year != yrCell) {sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(i, 1));}
    }
  }
}
```

But my recomendation is that you create a new sheet and use this formula in A1:

```
=IF(OR(ADJUSTMENTS!A1="ALL",ADJUSTMENTS!A1="all",ISBLANK(ADJUSTMENTS!A1)),QUERY(ADJUSTMENTS!A:Z,"SELECT *"),QUERY(ADJUSTMENTS!A:Z,"SELECT * WHERE R = "&ADJUSTMENTS!A1&""))
```

And you can use the same logic for your TEAM SALES sheet.

PS: If you use the formula make sure you replace the "Z" in both ADJUSTMENTS!A:Z with the last column of the sheet ADJUSTMENTS, so that it brings the whole sheet.

Comment: Thank you for these ideas. Sadly, the modified code did not work any faster than what I already had. Your idea about using query on another sheet was a great fix for the TEAM SALES sheet. However, it doesn't help with ADJUSTMENTS, because that one gets edited by the user. For now, I've added an unfortunate column for the filter view, but I'm still looking for a way to do it with a script.